# react-native run-android does not work :/

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, setup-project

Running react-native run-android in windows but get this error:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.   
  (node:8484) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
'gradlew.bat' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\cygwin64\home\Abderrahmane\app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)      
    at verifyENOENT (C:\cygwin64\home\Abderrahmane\app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)      
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\cygwin64\home\Abderrahmane\app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`
```

I have installed android studio and created a project
and I also run the emulator and i did

```
create-react-native-app project
react-native init project
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

Comment: have you tried implementing this one https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup or this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_environment_setup.htm one?

Comment: thank you so much :3

Comment: I will write it down in the answer section. Please give the checkmark if the solution helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one [react native environment setup from react native official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) or this [react native environment setup from tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_environment_setup.htm) one

Answer (score 0):

For android try this code:

```
 # Reset metro bundler cache : 
`npx react-native start --reset-cache`
    
# Remove Android assets cache : 
`cd android && ./gradlew clean`
    
# Relaunch metro server : 
`npx react-native run-android`
```

And to remove the "Jetifier", use:

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```